# error in apt upgrade (Problem with dns)

Tags: upgrade

hello i have problem:

[image]

run the following code before you have a problem:

curl -L https://install.pi-hole.net | bash

sudo systemctl start dnsmasq.service

Comment: your computer's connectivity (DNS) is busted.  You need to dig into your network configuration to make sure you have a DNS server configured on your system.

Comment: And, house rules here call for you to put your question in English, please.

Comment: @ThomasWard ok i understand but how do i do it. i can don´t install anything and configuration dns i know that should install bind configuration.

Answer (score 0):

i ran again the comand curl -L https://install.pi-hole.net | bash it worked again.